# Wordpress custom filed error: upload image return $_files empty

Tags: php, wordpress

This is about wordpress theme developing.

I added two custom fields ( text and upload image ) in category create and edit form. **All works well in edit form**. **In create form $_POST works well, but $_FILES is empty.**

I'm testing with Wamp on Windows locally, so there's enough space.

php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = "D:/Program Files/wamp/tmp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 64M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

post_max_size = 64M
```

functions.php

```
/*=====================================
=            category form            =
=====================================*/

// add file upload permission to category edit form
add_action ( 'category_edit_form', 'edit_form_tag');
function edit_form_tag() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#edittag').attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" );
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
}

add_action ( 'category_add_form', 'create_form_tag');
function create_form_tag() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#addtag').attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" );
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
}


//add extra fields to category create form hook
add_action ( 'category_add_form_fields', 'create_extra_category_fields');
//add extra fields to category create form callback function
function create_extra_category_fields( $tag ) {    //check for existing featured ID
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_{$t_id}");
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cat_style_type"><?php _e('Category Style Type'); ?></label>
        <select name="Cat_meta[cat_style_type]" id="cat_style_type" >
            <option value="text" <?php echo ($cat_meta['cat_style_type'] == 'text') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php _e('text'); ?></option>
            <option value="news" <?php echo ($cat_meta['cat_style_type'] == 'news') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php _e('news'); ?></option>
        </select>
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Required. Category style type: text or news.'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Category Image Url'); ?></label>
        <input type="file" name="cat_img" id="cat_Image_url" ><br />
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Image for category. If category\'s style is text, it\' optional; if category\'s style is news, it\'s required.'); ?></p>
        <img src="<?php echo $cat_meta['cat_img'] ? $cat_meta['cat_img'] : ''; ?>" style="max-width: 300px;height: auto;margin-top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <?php
}

//add extra fields to category edit form hook
add_action ( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'edit_extra_category_fields');
//add extra fields to category edit form callback function
function edit_extra_category_fields( $tag ) {    //check for existing featured ID
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_{$t_id}");
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_style_type"><?php _e('Category Style Type'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="Cat_meta[cat_style_type]" id="cat_style_type" >
                <option value="text" <?php echo ($cat_meta['cat_style_type'] == 'text') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php _e('text'); ?></option>
                <option value="news" <?php echo ($cat_meta['cat_style_type'] == 'news') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php _e('news'); ?></option>
            </select>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('Required. Category style type: text or news.'); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Category Image Url'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="cat_img" id="cat_Image_url" ><br />
            <p class="description"><?php _e('Image for category. If category\'s style is text, it\' optional; if category\'s style is news, it\'s required.'); ?></p>
            <img src="<?php echo $cat_meta['cat_img'] ? $cat_meta['cat_img'] : ''; ?>" style="max-width: 300px;height: auto;margin-top: 10px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

// save extra category extra fields hook
add_action ( 'create_category', 'save_extra_category_fileds');
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'save_extra_category_fileds');
// save extra category extra fields callback function
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Cat_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_{$t_id}");

        $cat_meta['cat_style_type'] = $_POST['Cat_meta']['cat_style_type'];

        if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        }

        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['cat_img'];

        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, array( 'test_form' => false ) );

        if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
            $cat_meta['cat_img'] = $movefile['url'];
        } else {
            echo $movefile['error'];
        }

        // save the option array
        update_option( "category_{$t_id}", $cat_meta );
    }
}

/*=====  End of category form  ======*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['CatMetaImg']` is using the input id.  Shouldn't that be the input name?

Comment: I fixed this error now, still not work. I can upload in edit form, but not work in create form. And I was using print_r($_FILES) before, it returns empty, so in fact it has nothing to do with $_FILES['CatMetaImg'] though it's wrong.